# Store Kit in-app purchases notification slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have followed an example tutorial online for integrating in-app purchases in to my app. It is all working fine purchasing and unlocking the extra content. However, the notification that gets posted for confirming the purchase can take from 4-9 seconds to appear. This does not make for a very consistent user experience and makes the app appear slow.

Has anyone else had the same problem as this or know of a fix for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long length of time and inconsistency is probably originating from the following:

When the user makes a purchase network messages will be sent to apples server - [the length of time this will take will be inconsistent depending on the distance from the server, the amount of nodes the message passes through and the quality of the connections you are using.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_time)

When the message reaches apples server it will need to be processed and a response generated - the length of this time will be inconsistent depending on the load currently affecting the server.

A confirmation then will be transmitted back over the network - same rules apply as for the outgoing message.

The device upon receiving the confirmation will display the alert to the user.

Unless you are able to make changes to the network which the message travels upon or can improve apples servers response times you will not be able to reduce the time or inconsistency.

A "solution" would be to display an activity indicator with a helpful message to the user explaining what is happening, if you plan on doing this recommend the following utility [DSActivityView](http://www.dejal.com/developer/dsactivityview). Its easy to use and quick to hook up and has been useful for me when faced with similar problems.

Comment: Okay, so using an activity indicator seems to be a great solution to the problem. Is there anything that StoreKit passes back that my progress indicator can use to stop animating and disappear when the notification is ready to pop up?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html 

Basically you want to register a SKPaymentTransactionObserver with the SKPaymentQueue. You will then receive the following callback
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions.
Which will contain the transaction (you will need to make sure that the transactions transactionState property is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased as the payment can also fail or be restored.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html is a very good guide detailing pretty much what you need to do. Make sure you read the "Adding a store to your application" section

Comment: I add an activity indicator as soon as I issue the SKProductsRequest, as otherwise it can feel like nothing's happening for several seconds. Occasionally the productsRequest:didRecieveResponse: delegate method never gets called, presumably due to a network issue. So when I add the activity indicator, I set it to automatically dismiss after 30 seconds, and I explicitly dismiss it when the user completes or cancels the transaction. I use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD. To dismiss it automatically after 30 seconds, call [activityIndicator hide:YES afterDelay:30].

Comment: I have a separate custom class that's handling all the purchasing and unlocking of the features. How can I make the purchasing class run a method on the current viewcontroller? i.e. The main viewcontroller adds a progress indicator and fires off a purchase message to the purchasing class, when the purchasing class gets a delegate call back to say it was successful, how can I then pass that back to the viewcontroller?

Comment: Ignore that, I've created a delegate method for the purchasing class and it seems to work great. Thanks for all your help!